# Microsoft Graph API won't work in production

Tags: php, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have my site set up so I can use Oauth for single sign on and added access to be able to post calendar entries made on my site to the user's outlook calendar.

Everything works on my dev environment but when I go to my calendar page in production it throws this error:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars`resulted in a`401 Unauthorized` response: { "error": { "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken", "message": "Access token validation failure."

I am using the same token I get from oAuth for the calendars. Is that not the right way to do it? And if not how do I go about the right way to do it and why would it work?

here is a part of my oauth page

```
        // Get an access token using the authorization code grant
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code'     => $_GET['code']
    ]);

    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] =$accessToken->getRefreshToken();
    $graph = new Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    //the sesion token for calendars expires faster than our token to stay in connect, so if it expires have the user sign back in
    try {
      $user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/calendars")
                    ->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {    //FAILS HERE
      // sessionTimeout(); exit; 
      var_dump($e);
    }
```

EDIT

throwing the token i get back into JWT I see that when in development my token has all the information including about what scopes i have. But in production the token is missing the "scp" field. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

EDIT 2
I thought maybe I would need a refresh token but that still gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you have use the same `APPID` and `AppSecret` in the dev environment and the production environment?

Comment: @kikang Yeah, my single sign on works but not the calendars

Comment: Could you please provide the different between the production and the development? Such as what did you changed on the production?

Comment: @kikang besides having two separate  entries for production and development in the app registration portal that have the same scopes and everything just different app id's and secret string and my development is mac os/ linux and the production is in centOS...nothing. The code bases are the same